# Can a person hypothetically fly without wings using electromagnetism?

Tags: planets, aliens, atmosphere, flight, electromagnetism

I just realized that I have no scientific reason as to why one of the races on my planet that I am writing can just fly.

No wings or anything they just have the ability to lift off the ground and land anywhere they want when they want.

The only biological difference I added to them compared to the race that is affected by gravity is that the ones that can fly have bigger lungs to help with air pressure while flying

So I started researching as to how they could possibly fly and one hypothetical is through electromagnetism as in perhaps their biology conducts an electromagnetic energy that could help them fly

Now looking at other planets magnetic fields it made me realize that for flight to hypothetically occur the planet would need a HIGH magnetic field.

So here's my questions
Is having a livable planet with a high magnetic field scientifically possible?

If yes does that mean that how high my character could fly if at all depends entirely on if they're on a planet with a high magnetic field and say for example they ended up on earth they wouldn't be able to fly due to earth having a weak magnetic field?

Comment: (To clarify the duplicate link, the answer is broadly "regardless of the strength of the planet's magnetic field, levitation isn't possible, if you're sticking to real science.")

Comment: Spiders do this. Their silk balloons are lifted by the electrostatic field that exists above the earth.

Comment: Hello @SketchLove, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. This was a rough first question and I apologize. It would have helped had you taken the time to read through our [tour] and at least the first to Help Center pages ([help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]) so you understood the rules of Stack Exchange and the limits of our Stack. (a) You're allowed to only ask one question per post. (b) It appears your primary question is "Can a human-habitable planet with a very strong magnetic field exist according to science as we understand it today?" Everything else is only the reason why you're asking. ...

Comment: ... It doesn't help that there's an unreasonably strong "everything as realistic as possible" trend on the Stack nowadays, and add to that you're asking for help doing something completely fantastic (sustained flight without an airfoil/balloon/rocket) and yet you want it to be scientific. On Earth, what you're asking for is impossible. Perhaps on Jupiter it's still impossible. Planetary fields are enormously large, but not particularly strong. A field strong enough to do what you're asking might get in the way of the brain's operation. BUT!!! That doesn't mean the idea isn't *really cool!* ...

Comment: ... So, are you sure that you're looking for an entirely scientific solution to your fantastic problem? Or is it enough to rationalize the idea by simply suggesting that your creatures have a highly magnetizable material in their blood, one science doesn't know about today, that allows them to "surf the planet's magnetic field?" Please keep in mind that as Newton said, for every action there's an equal and opposite reaction. A living creature might not be able to eat enough food to self-power an opposing magnetic field in order to fly. Science is a harsh task master.